# Excel VBA New range from selection

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with a complex UserDefined function that works only with a single and contiguous range of data.
Therfore I would like to create a function, which for a given range, returns me a new range emptied of blank cells, which will serve as input for the initial function.

Here's what what I have unsuccessfuly done so far:

```
Public Function NewRange(rng) As Range

    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Select
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Select
    rng = Union(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), _
      rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)).Select
Set NewRange = rng
End Function
```

Could you help me please in solving it?

Comment: `rng` is an object.  It must use the `Set` keyword.  So: `Set rng = ...`.  Also remove the `.select` at the end of the same statement.

Comment: You can't do that. It is not possible to create a range that is not on a worksheet. You'd need to change the UDF either to work with discontiguous ranges or to ignoreblank cells, or actually copy the data somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function NewRange(ByRef rng As Range) As Range
    Dim nrC As Range, nrF As Range

    If Len(rng.Value2) = 0 Then Set rng = rng.Parent.UsedRange.Cells(1, 1)
    Set rng = rng.CurrentRegion

    On Error Resume Next
    Set nrC = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set nrF = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

    Select Case True
        Case Not nrC Is Nothing And Not nrF Is Nothing: Set NewRange = Union(nrC, nrF)
        Case Not nrC Is Nothing:                        Set NewRange = nrC
        Case Not nrF Is Nothing:                        Set NewRange = nrF
    End Select
    If NewRange Is Nothing Then Set NewRange = rng.Parent.Cells(1)
End Function
```